# Is it a good practice to always use 'root' user in development environment?

Tags: linux, root, development-environment, sudo

There are three options when doing software development in a Linux environment:

1. Using your own user (e.g. mahdi)
2. Using root
3. Using nobody

I normally do all my development as 'root' but is it a best practice?

Comment: No,  using `root` is a worst practice :-/ . Use your ID, or create ids for operator accounts that will: run the software, have access to files, etc. Servers (sql, web, etc) should be run under there own 'named' accounts. `websphere`, `sybase`, etc. Good luck.

Comment: Voting to close a primarily opinion based, but I'd be surprised if anyone had an opinion other than "No. It is a terrible practice". But then everyone is entitled to their own opinion (no matter how stupid it is ;-)

Comment: I don't think this is opinion based. These options are completely different and can provide different limitations/features to the developer.

Comment: Use your own personal account. Use `root`, preferably via `sudo` ***if and only if*** you actually need to. (Unless you absolutely never make misteaks; then feel free to use `root` for everything.)

Comment: @mahdix - Your argument against "opinion based" is exactly the argument that it is opinion based and that there is no one answer, it is based on the context etc. The comments are starting to paint you a pretty clear picture though...

Comment: The reason you never use root for development. `target=/path/to/dir/to/del/`, .. more code in between `target=${target##*del}; rm -r target`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are plenty of reasons to not use root for general usage in Linux. 
Barring that: Using root in a *development* environment will cause headaches if you are not far removed from deployment. In my opinion (and practice) development should mimic production as closely as possible. Doing development in super-user permissions is usually very different than how the software will be run (as a web user, privileged user, etc).

This will hide things and cause issues further down the line.

Take an example: in your code you read/write a temporary file in /opt. This works great in dev, tests pass, everything is great. The code goes out to production. /optis owned by root:root with 700 in production and the application runs as apache. The reading/writing will fail.

Answer (score 2):

> One liner answer is you should never grant the root access to developers.

It is a good practice to keep the DEV environment as closer as possible to PROD environment. Developers often need to carry out tool installations, service configurations, file creations and file modifications. These process can be well managed by automating the process with tools like Chef, Jenkins and creating different access like "devops", "commit", "devadmins'. Wherever needed "devadmins" can have sudo access. This way the process will be organized and no one will be able to make unauthorized changes.

Imagine if your Dev-team is scattered across various geographical regions, working on different timezone. Someone makes unauthorized changes in the server from India and the developer in North-America will wonder, if it is not properly communicated.

> root should only be used when there are no other option left

Comment: Your answer assumes a certain kind of development.